# AngularJS after redirect from app to app, the default page is not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 html files, one is index.html and another is project.html.
They have their own app.js and project.js, and share the same controllers.js.

I defined ng-app="app" and ng-app="project" seperately, however when I login and redirect to project.html, or I logout from project to index.html, the default page sometimes is not loading. I'm using ui-router, the default state seems not triggered occasionally. Anything wrong? Thanks.

**Update**
Seems it's nothing to do with redirection. Even I just enter the url (get) again and again, it stops loading default state once in a while. If I force refresh it works again.

Comment: I think you should declare as same app (ng-app="app") in different page, you can use route or template to render back

Comment: actually I tried that already, same. seems angular cached module and not init the module when redirect to the page. but sometimes it does reinit again.

Comment: This happens to Chrome only. Never happens on Safari. I guess chrome is 'too smart' to cache js object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's the Chrome extension 'AngularJS Batarang' causing all these problems.

Do not install it.

Comment: wow - thanks for sharing this.... was having a similar problem and was mind boggling, turning off Batarang got it working as expected.  Stoopid extensions...